# Why does my Instagram load more button keep throwing internal server error?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, instagram

I am building a relatively small app in laravel.

Currently I am trying to create a load more button to load more images into a container in the view.

Would anyone know when clicking load more I get an internal server error?

Here is my set up:

View for my images:

```
$instagram = new Instagram\Instagram;

    $instagram->setAccessToken($_SESSION['instagram_access_token']);
    $token = $_SESSION['instagram_access_token'];
    //$clientID = $_SESSION['client_id'];

    $current_user = $instagram->getCurrentUser();
    $tag = $instagram->getTag('folkclothing');
    $media = $tag->getMedia(isset($_GET['max_tag_id']) ? array( 'max_tag_id' => $_GET['max_tag_id'] ) : null);


    $liked_media = $current_user->getLikedMedia();
echo '<section id="images">';

    foreach ( $media as $item ) {

        echo '<article class="instagram-image">';
        // define the form and set the action to POST to send the data to this script
        echo '<form class="forms" action="'; echo URL::current(); echo '" method="post">';

            $id = $item->getId();

            echo '<a class="fancybox" href="' . $item->link . '"><img src="' . $item->images->standard_resolution->url . '" /></a>';
            if ( $current_user->likes($item) ){
                echo '<button class="ajax instabtn unlike icon-heart" type="submit" name="action" value="Unlike"></button>';
            } else {
                echo '<button class="ajax instabtn like icon-heart" type="submit" name="action" value="Like"></button>';
            }
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'; echo $id; echo '">';

            echo '<p>'; echo $item->likes->count; echo '</p>';
            //echo '<p>'.$item->getId().'</p>';
            //echo '<p>By: <em>' . $item->user->username . '</em> </p>';
            //echo '<p>Date: ' . date('d M Y h:i:s', $item->created_time) . '</p>';
            //echo '<p>$item->comments->count . ' comment(s). ' . $item->likes->count . ' likes. ';

        echo '</form>';
        echo '</article>';
    }
    echo '</section>';
```

Here the instagram class generates the images and puts them into the div through a loop. Below is a load more button storing the data need in it.

Load more button:

```
echo "<br><button id=\"more\" data-maxid=\"{$media->getNextMaxTagId()}\" data-tag=\"{$tag}\">Load more ...</button>";
```

And then there is an ajax view that stores the relevant data for the images to be found for the next page:

```
<?php

// set up autoloader
function app_autoloader($class) {
  include './' . $class . '.php';
}
spl_autoload_register('app_autoloader');

 // Initialize class for public requests
  $instagram = new Instagram\Instagram;

  // Receive AJAX request and create call object
  $tag = $_GET['tag'];
  $clientID = $instagram->getApiKey();


  $media = $tag->getMedia(isset($_GET['max_tag_id']) ? array( 'max_tag_id' => $_GET['max_tag_id'] ) : null);

  $call = new stdClass;
  $call->next_max_id = $maxID;
  $call->next_url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{$tag}/media/recent?client_id={$clientID}&max_tag_id={$media->getNextMaxTagId()}";

  // Receive new data
  $media = $instagram->pagination($call);

  // Collect everything for json output
  $images = array();
  foreach ($media->data as $data) {
    $images[] = $data->images->standard_resolution->url;
  }

  echo json_encode(array(
    'next_id' => $media->getNextMaxTagId,
    'images'  => $images
  ));
```

This page finds the tag and gets the media for that tag and finds the next_max_id. In my jquery I use and ajax call to get this data and load the images into my div but instead I get an internal server error like so:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://client:8888/ajax?tag=client&max_tag_id=1374869525975&_=137571153802
```

Does anyone have an idea why it would not produce the results? I know its not too far off.

Cheers

Comment: Well, what do the server log files say? Little sense in diggin' in the dark...

Comment: The server log files dont say anything, I am in mamp pro and nothing has come up in the php error log

Comment: what happens when you actually browse to the url you are trying to load?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "php error log"... I was referring to the http server logs. If you get an error 500 then there must be something in there...

Comment: I get Error rendering view: [instagram.ajax]

Call to undefined method Instagram\Instagram::getApiKey()

Comment: Where can I find http server logs locally if I use mamp?

Comment: Does anyone have an idea on this at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue in the end.

There were conflicting php values that were not being picked up properly and sending the wrong url to be passed through.

In the end I modified the ajax page like so:

```
<?php

// set up autoloader
function app_autoloader($class) {
  include './' . $class . '.php';
}
spl_autoload_register('app_autoloader');

// start session
session_start();

if (!isset( $_SESSION['instagram_access_token'] ) ) {
$auth = new Instagram\Auth( $auth_config );
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
      $_SESSION['instagram_access_token'] = $auth->getAccessToken( $_GET['code'] );
      header( 'Location: ' . REDIRECT_AFTER_AUTH );
      exit;
  } else {
    $auth->authorize();
  }
  exit;
}


  $instagram = new Instagram\Instagram;

  $instagram->setAccessToken($_SESSION['instagram_access_token']);
  $token = $_SESSION['instagram_access_token'];
    //$clientID = $_SESSION['client_id'];

  $current_user = $instagram->getCurrentUser();
  $tag = $instagram->getTag('folkclothing');

  $media = $tag->getMedia(isset($_GET['max_tag_id']) ? array( 'max_tag_id' => $_GET['max_tag_id'] ) : null);
/*   $params = isset( $_GET['max_tag_id'] ) ? array( 'max_tag_id' => $_GET['max_tag_id'] ) : null; */

  /* $media = $tag->getMedia($params); */
  /* $next_page = $media->getNext(); */

/*

  // Receive new data
  $imageMedia = $instagram->pagination($media);
*/

  // Collect everything for json output
  $images = array();
  foreach ($media as $data) {
    $images[] = array($data->images->standard_resolution->url,$data->link,$data->getId(),$data->likes->count);
  }

  echo json_encode(array(
    'next_id' => $media->getNextMaxTagId(),
    'images'  => $images
  ));
```

I hope this helps anyone looking to do the same thing here :)

Cheers